# left alignment for equation using split

Tags: align

Goodmorning everyone, 
I need your help to figure out how to align to the left an equation with a split command inside. I've alredy read all the post about it but nothing worked. Any other ideas? Thanks
Andrea

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
i(v)=-(\frac{520}{2000})ln(\dfrac{520}{2000})-(\frac{1480}{2000})ln(\frac{11480}{2000})=0.573,\\
p(l)=\frac{800}{2000}=0.4, \\ 
i(l)=-(\frac{320}{800})ln(\dfrac{320}{800})-(\frac{480}{800})ln(\frac{480}{800})=0.673,\\   
p(r)=\frac{1200}{2000}=0.6, \hspace{0.5cm} i(r)=-(\frac{200}{1200})ln(\dfrac{200}{1200})-(\frac{1000}{1200})ln(\frac{1000}{1200})=0.451,\\
 I=0.573-0.4(0.673)-0.6(0.451)=0.0332
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: split is designed for _aligned_ equations but you have no alignment points marked, use `&=` not `=`  If you want left aligned equations generally use the `fleqn` option to `amsmath`

Comment: also use `\ln` not `ln`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to implementing David Carlisle's comments -- provide alignment points, and write `\ln` rather than `ln` -- you should also enlarge the parentheses on the right-hand side of the first five equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
i(v)&=-\Bigl(\frac{520}{2000}\Bigr)\ln\Bigl(\dfrac{520}{2000}\Bigr)
      -\Bigl(\frac{1480}{2000}\Bigr)\ln\Bigl(\frac{11480}{2000}\Bigr)
      =0.573,\\
p(l)&= \frac{800}{2000}=0.4, \\ 
i(l)&=-\Bigl(\frac{320}{800}\Bigr)\ln\Bigl(\dfrac{320}{800}\Bigr)
      -\Bigl(\frac{480}{800}\Bigr)\ln\Bigl(\frac{480}{800}\Bigr)
      =0.673,\\   
p(r)&= \frac{1200}{2000}=0.6, \\
i(r)&=-\Bigl(\frac{200}{1200}\Bigr)\ln\Bigl(\dfrac{200}{1200}\Bigr)
      -\Bigl(\frac{1000}{1200}\Bigr)\ln\Bigl(\frac{1000}{1200}\Bigr)
      =0.451,\\[1ex]
I&=   0.573-0.4(0.673)-0.6(0.451)=0.0332
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the parentheses should be `\bigg`, right?

Comment: @Someone - As the old saying goes, there's no arguing about taste. That said, I find that `\bigg` parentheses in lines 1, 3, and 5 are needlessly and distractingly big. By "distractingly", I mean that the parentheses are so big as to draw a lot of attention to themselves, rather than to the material they enclose. That's why I went with `\Big`. Looking that these equations again for the first time in more than four years, I thiink an argument could be made for omitting the large parentheses entirely...

Comment: I see what you mean.