# LaTeX splitting an equation

Tags: align, amsmath, split

Can someone please tell me why this code isn't working? I've used this before to split lines and even then, it seemed hit and miss to me, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please? Many thanks

````
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
q+ dt\left[\frac{17q\left(\frac{ q_{i+1} - q_{i-1}}{2\Delta x} \right)}{7h}-\frac{9q^2\left(\frac{ h_{i+1} - h_{i-1}}{2\Delta x} \right)}{7h^2}\frac{1}{\epsilon Re} \left( \frac{5h \epsilon B_0 \cos \theta \left(\frac{ h_{i+1} - h_{i-1}}{2\Delta x} \right)}{6 Ca} - \\
\frac{5h \epsilon^3 \left(\frac{ h_{i+2} -2h_{i+1}+2h_{i-1}- h_{i-2}}{(2\Delta x)^3} \right)}{6 Ca}+\frac{5 q}{2h^2}-\frac{5h B_0 \sin \theta}{6 Ca}\right)\right] + dt\left[\frac{\epsilon}{Re} \left( \frac{-9 \left(\frac{ q_{i+1} -2q_{i}+q_{i-1}}{(\Delta x)^2} \right)}{2} +\\
\frac{9 \left(\frac{ q_{i+1} - q_{i-1}}{2\Delta x} \right) \left(\frac{ h_{i+1} - h_{i-1}}{2\Delta x} \right)}{2h}-\frac{4q\left(\frac{ h_{i+1} - h_{i-1}}{2\Delta x} \right)^2}{h^2} + \\
\frac{6q\left(\frac{ h_{i+1} -2h_{i}+h_{i-1}}{(\Delta x)^2} \right)
\left(\frac{ q_{i+1} -2q_{i}+q_{i-1}}{(\Delta x)^2} \right)}{h} \right)\right] \end{split} \end{equation} ```
````

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You asked, "Can someone please tell me why this code isn't working?" A: because `\left ... \right directives are not allowed to span line breaks.

Comment: It is necessary to use referring the absolute correct comments of @Mico to use, for example, `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`. Actually I not find the mistakes of your brackets.

Comment: the left right? really? i had \left[ and \right] before and it worked, but not \left( or \right) ...

Comment: @SaraIsmail-Sutton You can see this link to understand better: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425151/left-alignment-for-equation-using-split

Comment: You followed up, "i had `\left[` and `\right]` before and it worked". Yes, but those directives span line breaks?

Comment: No when you had `\left[...\right]` they must have been on the same line, you can not span `\\ ` or `&` in the alignment.

Comment: oh on line breaks right i missed that ok thanks, ill try with that update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation has one serious and one more subtle problem.

- The serious problem is caused by `\left[` and `\left(` in row 1 are matched with `\right)` and `\right]` in row 2; ditto for rows 3 and 4. This cannot work. I suggest you use `\Biggl[`, `\Biggl(`, `\Biggr)`, and `\Biggr]` instead.
- The more subtle issue is that even though you're using a `split` environment, you're not providing any alignment points via `&` symbols. This results in all four rows getting smooshed to the right. Not good. See the solution below for suggested placements of these markers.
- Not an outright error, but there's a typographic inconsistency that arises because different parenthesis size result from the indiscriminate use of `\left(` and `\right)` directives. I suggest you use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` throughout.
- The code below also uses `\mathstrut` directives in the six parenthetic fraction expressions that have `2\Delta` in the denominator. That way, they're placed consistently with the parenthetic fraction terms that have either `(\Delta x)^2` or `(2\Delta x)^3` in the denominators.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
q&+ dt\Biggl[
 \frac{17q  \bigl(\frac{ q_{i+1} - q_{i-1}}{2\Delta x\mathstrut} \bigr)}{7h}
 -\frac{9q^2\bigl(\frac{ h_{i+1} - h_{i-1}}{2\Delta x\mathstrut} \bigr)}{7h^2}
 \frac{1}{\epsilon Re}  
\Biggl( \frac{5h \epsilon B_0 \cos\theta 
  \bigl(\frac{ h_{i+1} - h_{i-1}}{2\Delta x\mathstrut} \bigr)}{6 Ca}   \\
&\qquad\quad - \frac{5h \epsilon^3 
  \bigl(\frac{ h_{i+2} -2h_{i+1}+2h_{i-1}- h_{i-2}}{(2\Delta x)^3} \bigr)}{6 Ca}
       +\frac{5 q}{2h^2}-\frac{5h B_0 \sin \theta}{6 Ca}
\Biggr)\Biggr] \\
 &+ dt \Biggl[\frac{\epsilon}{Re} \Biggl( \frac{-9 
  \bigl(\frac{ q_{i+1} -2q_{i}+q_{i-1}}{(\Delta x)^2} \bigr)}{2} 
       +\frac{9 \bigl(\frac{ q_{i+1} - q_{i-1}}{2\Delta x\mathstrut} \bigr) 
                \bigl(\frac{ h_{i+1} - h_{i-1}}{2\Delta x\mathstrut} \bigr)}{2h} \\
&\qquad\quad
-\frac{4q\bigl(\frac{ h_{i+1} - h_{i-1}}{2\Delta x\mathstrut} \bigr)^2}{h^2} 
+\frac{6q\bigl(\frac{ h_{i+1} -2h_{i}+h_{i-1}}{(\Delta x)^2} \bigr)
         \bigl(\frac{ q_{i+1} -2q_{i}+q_{i-1}}{(\Delta x)^2} \bigr)}{h} 
\Biggr)\Biggr]
\end{split} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```